# fetch data to custom tab in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, sales, tabs

I have created a custom tab in Sales Order View in Magento admin panel.
On clicking the tab, I need to fetch the details from a table called as "`sales_flat_sub_order`".

Answer (score 0):

Sachin,
Suppose that you have follow [Atwix block](http://www.atwix.com/magento/new-tab-product-edit-page/)

On your render class you get easy order from registry variable of current order:

```
$order= Mage::registry('current_order');
```

if you do not define model for `sales_flat_sub_order` then `you need define model class` .Then using this model you can get data.

[See](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/) how can create model for a table.

Comment: Hey amit , i have alreaady added the tab in the order view ("Suborder").on a click of it, i have to fetch the value from the table.

Comment: Hey buddy, im a newbee in magento :P pls llet me know the files where i have to change. My requirement is that, there will be multiple suborders created for every single order.So on click of the Suborder tab , i have to fetch the values from the existing suborder table. I went through your post link, but im confused as to where to include the files and data. pls suggest

Comment: have  you already create custom tab.Please show that code.

Comment: i have followed this link, its working fine, http://www.opensourceforwebtechnologies.com/how-to-add-custom-tab-on-sales-order-view-in-magento/#comment-363    Now on a click of that tab , table values have to be fetched

Comment: I have followed the below link http://www.opensourceforwebtechnologies.com/how-to-add-custom-tab-on-sales-order-view-in-magento/#comment-363

Comment: I will check sortly